# Do we want site-specific editing guidance?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, editing

With our newly reached "graduated" (I really shouldn't put that in quotes) status, I expect a significant influx of new users, be it through migration or otherwise being drawn in by the thrill of a freshly graduated site.

With these users incoming, I also expect a significant inbound amount of edits, as well as lots of new people, that gain the editing-privilege to review and edit, quite possibly without knowing [our rules for editing code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5179/37660)

This can mean a significant amount of necessary user-based moderation, even though @SimonForsberg got our ever-helping Duga to look for exactly that kind of edit and [warn regulars in the 2nd monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24005204#24005204)

That said I think we can actually prevent a lot of these well-intentioned edits by providing clear guidance as to what is an acceptable edit and what is not.

Do we want such a site-specific set of guidance?

If not, what did I (aside from the necessity to implement it) overlook?

Answer (score 10):

What would really help is if all these "well intentioned" edits were filtered through review queues instead as people learn.... unfortunately, that threshold for people is still with beta-level reputation levels, so that filter is not as useful as it should be.

On the other hand, this is a perceived problem that may not in fact happen (we would have to "negotiate" with a site to be a migration target, etc. so that sort of thing won't just happen)....

So, this is a possible solution to a problem which may or may not happen, and it may or may not be circumvented if/when the SE staff properly graduate the site to the point where new-to-the-site users are not established enough to make the editing mistakes.

Consider that edit privilege comes at 1000 reputation on beta sites.... (us), but at 2000 rep on full sites, that double-the-threshold will be a significant help to prevent well-intentioned mistakes.

Comment: While I get your point (and frustration), we really should write down our editing guidelines anyway. Otherwise, we'll someday end up with 2k users who don't know any better.